# How to place latitude and longitude with null projection in d3?

Tags: d3.js, geo

I am trying to plot some latitude and longitude points with a pre-projected topojson using d3.

Here is how i created my pre-projected topojson

```
geoproject "d3.geoMercator().fitSize([960, 500], d)" < india.json > source.json
geo2topo -q 1e5 source.json > source.topojson
```

With the above topojson I am able to draw the map perfectly, but I am not sure how to place a lat-long point in the map.

Here is my code.

```
   var india = topojson.feature(indTopo, indTopo.objects.source);

    var proxyProjection = d3.geoIdentity()
            .fitExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]], india);

    var path = d3.geoPath().projection(proxyProjection);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "states")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(india.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", "gray")
        .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", point[0])
        .attr("cy", point[1]);

    //for lat-long to xy

    var mercator = d3.geoMercator()
    .fitSize([width,height], india);

   var point = mercator([80.2707, 13.0827]);
```

But it is not working as expected.

Comment: you first append and place the circle and then you calculate where it should go

Comment: I tried, but comes in a different location.

Comment: put your india json at http://myjson.com

Comment: You need to know the projection parameters used to project your topojson - fitSize/fitExtent set projection translate and scale, you can find out these values by logging scale/translate, such as: `projection.fitExtent(...).scale()`. Then use those values to define a projection to place your points, while the topojson will continue to use a null projection in the client (as it is projected already).

Comment: @AndrewReid, Thanks for the idea, it worked perfectly. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sd5bLo7/1/). However when I change the dimension it is not working properly [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/08oehda9/1/). I am using d3.geoIdentity() to fit into the new size.

Comment: @AndrewReid I created a new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj3hgsny/1/) and seems it is working fine now. But I am not sure it the correct way of doing it.